# Generar excel desde boton sin necesidad de mostrar tabla en html

Tags: php, javascript, html, excel

Buenas quiero quiero generar un excel desde un boton pero sin necesidad de mostrar la tabla, que el boton contenga la consulta en mysql

Yo genero un archivo excel con este script.

```
var tableToExcel = (function() {
          var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
            , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
            , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
            , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
          return function(table, name) {
            if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
            var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
            window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
          }
        })()
```

Pero quiero generar un excel en general desde un boton sin necesidad de tener que mostrar una tabla.

Comment: Podrías compartir el código de lo que tienes hecho hasta ahora? para que así sea más fácil ayudarte con lo que quieres hacer

Comment: Te invito a que leas el siguiente enlace https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask para que te des una idea de como formular correctamente tu pregunta.

Comment: Modifique un poco mi post espero puedan entender mi duda...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucione de la siguiente manera:

Cree el Form donde envio los datos para mi consulta:

```
<form action="src/GeneralReport.php" role='form' method="POST">
                        <input type='hidden' value='<?php echo $_POST["fechaInicio"] ?>' name='fechaInicio'  class='form-control'>
                        <input type='hidden' value='<?php echo $_POST["fechaFin"] ?>' name='fechaFin' class='form-control'>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-md-2 py-1" name="test" value="Generar Reporte">
</form>
```

Y cree un nuevo archivo **"GeneralReport.php"** Donde ingrese la siguiente informacion.

```
    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","Database");

    $fechaInicio=$_POST['fechaInicio'];
    $fechaFin=$_POST['fechaFin'];

    header('Content-type:application/xls');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=DTLostTimeSMT.xls');
    ?>

    <table id="TableDetailGeneral" class="table table-striped table-hover">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Line</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="TablaDetail">
                        <?php
                            $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","psb_smt");
                            if (mysqli_connect_errno())
                            {
                                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                            }
                            $sql="SELECT * FROM BaseDeDatos 
                            WHERE DateTimes BETWEEN '".$fechaInicio."  00:00:00' AND '".$fechaFin." 23:59:00'"; 
                            $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql); 
                            try {
                                $i=1;
                                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                printf ("<tr>");
                                printf ("<td scope='row'>".$i++."</td>");
                                printf ("<td scope='row'>".$row["DateTime"]."</td>");
                                printf ("<td scope='row'>".$row["psb_line"]."</td>");
</td>");
                                }   
                                    } catch (PDOException $e) {
                                        echo $e ->getMessage();
                                    }
                            mysqli_free_result($result);
                            mysqli_close($con);
                        ?>            
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Que por lo que entiendo las siguientes lineas son las que generar el archivo de excel de la pagina.

```
header('Content-type:application/xls');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=DTLostTimeSMT.xls');
```

Answer (score 0):

Si entiendo bien, puedes poner el html como string directamente en lugar de hacer `document.getElementById(table)`:

```
var tableToExcel = (function() {
          var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
            , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
            , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
            , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
          return function(table, name) {
            var table = `<table><tr>mi tabla</td></table>` //<-- Aqui
            var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table}//<-- Aqui no hacemos .innerHTML
            window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
          }
        })();
```